# Approximation of PI

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to solve that product, in the following equation. 
The problem that I feel that is a recursive problem, but I don't know where is the base case? 
otherwise, should I simplify the square root terms into simplified version and use iterative method ?
[image: eaa]

[image]

Comment: what did you do so far, please post your code

Comment: I just want to know what approach to solve the problem :) for recursive approach what is the base case for example ?

Comment: No recursion is needed.  Start with `a=sqrt(2)`, then `a=sqrt(2+a)`.  Do that in a loop.

Comment: @ajb I thought about reducing it like you said too :) You mean sqrt(2)/2 ?

Comment: @Mahmoud No, I meant what I said.  Try doing it that way, by hand (using square-root symbols, not computing it), and you'll see how it fits into the formula.

Comment: @Mahmoud Actually, what I wrote is exactly what was in your question as z(i).  I just didn't notice it at the time.  Anyway, although z(i) is expressed recursively in the formula, you don't need to implement it using recursion.

Comment: @ajb: Agree, recursion is the wrong approach here

Comment: It looks like the curly braces near the z(1), z(2), ... in the math formula are intended to bracket only the _numerators_ of the fractions.  It's not completely clear just from the layout of the braces, but looking at the formula for z(i) should make it clear what's meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, your function `z` appears to be recursive, and your base-case should probably be z(0) or z(1).

so you should have something like

```
public static double z(double i)
{
    if(i < 1)
    {
        //error
    }
    else if(i == 1)
    {
        return C;  // where C is some arbitrary constant, your base case: Z(1);
    }
    else
    {
        return sqrt(2 + z(i-1));
    }

}
```

Comment: correct, but the homework was his job. (At least the value of C remains to be solved :-)

Comment: Using a double for the index is an invitation to disaster.

Comment: Using a double as counter, you cannot be assured to hit `i == 1` exactly (due to well known limitations of floating point arithmetic). It clearly should be an integer.

Comment: @GyroGearless Well, yes, you can be assured of this, assuming `i` starts out at something less than `2**50` or so.  The arithmetic _will_ always work out exactly.  But you're right, it's bad practice to use doubles for values that are supposed to hold integers, and in most cases you can't count on `==` when working with floating-point math.

Comment: Good point, although i just could check this up to i=62795 before running into a StackOverflowError (pun intended)

Answer (score 1):

The stop condition is when z reaches 1: z(1)= sqrt(2).